# Sort and show recyclerview with firebase

Tags: android, sorting, android-layout, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list I want to sort them and show them in their rightful category. If Item.Percentage is high, in the first category. If it is medium in the second and so on.

I would rather have 1 recyclerview but I have no idea how that could be achieved.

[image]

This is how I would like it to look like.
[image]

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taboverview, container, false);

    //Create the reference to get data from Firebase.
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        userId = user.getUid();
    }

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView2 = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2);
    recyclerView3 = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview3);



    sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(String.format("%s", userId), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    completeList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(obd2Id)) {
        //SharedPref for each user
        obdForFirebase = String.valueOf(sharedpreferences.getInt(obd2Id, 0));
        databaseReference = database.getReference("OBD2DeviceId").child(obdForFirebase);

        updateList();
    }


    //first recycler
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(
            new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    adapter = new ConditionAdapter(completeList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //2 recycler
    recyclerView2 = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview2);
    recyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(
            new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    adapter2 = new ConditionAdapter(completeList);
    recyclerView2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    //3 recycler
    recyclerView3 = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview3);
    recyclerView3.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView3.setLayoutManager(
            new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    adapter3 = new ConditionAdapter(completeList);
    recyclerView3.setAdapter(adapter3);
    return v;
}


private void updateList() {
    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("conditionProcentage");
    query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            completeList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Condition.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Condition condition = dataSnapshot.getValue(Condition.class);
            int index = getItemIndex(condition);
            completeList.set(index, condition);
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Condition condition = dataSnapshot.getValue(Condition.class);

            //int index = getItemIndex(condition);
            //list.remove(index);
            //adapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private int getItemIndex(Condition condition) {
    int index = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < completeList.size(); i++) {
        if (completeList.get(i).getId().equals(condition.getId())) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

private void prepareList() {
    goodConditionList = new ArrayList<>();
    mediumConditionList = new ArrayList<>();
    problemConditionList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; completeList.size() > i; i++) {

        if (completeList.get(i).getConditionProcentage() >= 61) {
            goodConditionList.add(completeList.get(i));
        }
        if (completeList.get(i).getConditionProcentage() <= 60 && completeList.get(i).getConditionProcentage() > 40) {
            mediumConditionList.add(completeList.get(i));
        } else {
            problemConditionList.add(completeList.get(i));
        }
    }

    completeList.clear();
    completeList.addAll(goodConditionList);
    completeList.addAll(mediumConditionList);
    completeList.addAll(problemConditionList);

}
```

My first idea was to get a complete list, sort it. And create 3 list. Sort and add the items to the list they belong and add a title with it and add it to the complete list. But that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do this all with one RecyclerView. What you want to to do is create a RecyclerView.Adapter that supports more than one type. You can have as many as you'd like but I'd recommend two, i.e. regular list item displaying the car part data (TextView, and progress bar) and another for the section header (indicates if the following items are  "Working Fine", "Problem Started", and "Problem Detected").

The RecyclerView.Adapter will then take take a data set that contains both the car part data (title and progress value) and header section data. I'd recommend is to create a new object type that encapsulates what this RecyclerView can display, and store either the title of the car part or the title of the header section. This information should be provided to the RecyclerView.Adapter in the correct order it should be displayed in.

The last part you need to implement is the loading function. This is where you will want to read all of the car diagnostic data from Firebase and then begin sorting it into your three categories "Working Fine", "Problem Started", and "Problem Detected". You'll pay special care to make make sure everything is in the correct position inside of the data set before giving it to the Adapter. For example, you don't wanna inter-mix "Working Fine" data with "Problem Detected" and  "Problem Started" because the section headers will become inaccurate and confuse your users.

Comment: Okay nice, i will try to work on this solution. I'm not and experienced Android developer, but I will try. Do you have a link for example of this adapter with list and header?

Comment: I don't have any links but I'm sure you can find a few tutorials on making a sectioned RecyclerView.

Comment: Found this, anything better than this: https://robusttechhouse.com/tutorial-how-to-add-header-to-recyclerview-in-android/

Comment: @HurricaneFFs That tutorial won't help you because it's covers adding a header to a RecyclerView instead of sections.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Found the lib, this is it right? https://github.com/IntruderShanky/Sectioned-RecyclerView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4495